ROS2 Synchronization Issue: Pose and GNSS Data Out of Sync with Different Update Rates (200 Hz vs 100 Hz)
Title:
ROS2 Synchronization Issue: Pose and GNSS Data Out of Sync with Different Update Rates (200 Hz vs 100 Hz)

Body:
I am working with ROS2 Humble and trying to synchronize the data from two topics in my system: one from a GNSS sensor and another from a pose estimation node. However, I am experiencing synchronization issues, where one data stream (GNSS) seems to lag behind the other (pose) by around 2-3 meters during playback.
Setup:

ROS2 version: Humble
Topic 1 (/ros_pospac_bridge/pose_stamped): Pose data from a pose estimation node, publishing at an average rate of 200 Hz.
Topic 2 (/applanix/lvx_client/gnss/fix): GNSS data from a GNSS sensor, publishing at an average rate of 100 Hz.
GitHub Repository for GNSS Publisher: gps_publisher_ros2humble

Problem:

The pose data updates more frequently than the GNSS data, and this causes synchronization problems. Specifically, the GNSS data often seems to stop earlier or lag behind by about 2-3 meters, even when both streams are supposed to be synchronized (around the same timestamp).
Both topics should cover the same path, but due to the difference in update rates, the pose data seems to advance ahead of the GNSS fix at certain points.

What I’ve Tried:

I've checked the publishing frequencies of both topics using ros2 topic hz:

Pose data (/ros_pospac_bridge/pose_stamped) is updating at ~200 Hz.
GNSS data (/applanix/lvx_client/gnss/fix) is updating at ~100 Hz.


The mismatch in rates seems to be causing one stream to move faster than the other, leading to desynchronization.

My Questions:

How can I ensure that both the pose and GNSS data streams remain synchronized, despite the difference in update rates?
Is there a way to interpolate or align the slower GNSS data with the more frequent pose updates?
Would adjusting the GNSS update rate to match the pose rate help resolve this, or is there a better approach in ROS2 to synchronize topics with different frequencies?
Are there existing ROS2 packages or tools to synchronize data streams from multiple topics efficiently?

Additional Information:

I am using the rosbag2 for playback, but the same issue happens during live processing.
I’ve considered resampling or time synchronization but am unsure of the best approach in ROS2.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to properly synchronize these two data streams would be greatly appreciated!

Tags:
ros2 data-synchronization gnss pose-estimation topic rosbag

What synchronization mechanism are you using? Are you using message filters?

@bcn I don't use any specific mechanisms.But, when I try to run this code I provided with github link, and rosbag file. Their paths are not going in same speed.

What you're encountering is not strictly a synchronization issue with the update rates. What you're observing is that different sensors have different characteristics such as uncertainty, bias, and observation latency. The sampling rate that you've seen adds a layer on top of that.
The generic term for what you're looking to do is sensor fusion. And especially for vehicle pose estimation the Kalman Filter is one of the most common mechanisms to do this. Especially the Extended Kalman Filter, which you can find several implementations of in ROS packages. One I would suggest looking at is fuse available in most current ROS versions
